# Cron job doesn't run (Perl & Centos)

Tags: perl, cron

In my /etc/crontab file I write:

```
* * * * * PLACK_ENV=development -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ /home/adrian/app/script/db/log_to_db.pl
```

To make a cron job run every minute. The job is running the log_to_db.pl perl script, which inserts data to my database.

When I run in my terminal
PLACK_ENV=development -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ /home/adrian/app/script/db/log_to_db.pl 
It's OK! The script runs.

But the cron job isn't working!
What can be wrong?

PD: My script starts like

```
    #!/usr/bin perl 
    ....
```

My cron log prints:

```
Jul  8 20:29:01 dev0001 crond[1829]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jul  8 20:29:01 dev0001 crond[1829]: (CRON) bad username (/etc/crontab)
Jul  8 20:30:01 dev0001 crond[1829]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jul  8 20:30:01 dev0001 crond[1829]: (CRON) bad username (/etc/crontab)
Jul  8 20:30:01 dev0001 CROND[13504]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S DISK 1 1)
```

Comment: there is a space between `bin` and `perl`

Comment: @Bill unfortunately that does not seem to be the problem. i changed the shebang to #!/usr/bin/perl but nothing happens...

Comment: have you actually read the error message you get in your cron log??? I'm guessing no...

Comment: it says "bad username". I guessed running this as root was not good due to the nature of script, so I add the same line in crontab -u adrian -e, and get a log: "Jul ul  8 20:53:01 dev0001 CROND[13933]: (adrian) CMD (PLACK_ENV=development perl -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ /home/adrian/app/script/db/log_to_db.pl )" But The database is not changed, not even the "last update time" column, which suggests the job isn't being done..

Comment: Isn't the path to the perl executable supposed to be in there somewhere, like before the `-I`? It looks like you are executing the command `-I`, with predictable results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a username when putting it in the system crontab

`* * * * * adrian PLACK_ENV=development -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ /home/adrian/app/script/db/log_to_db.pl`

But as @jithin said, putting this in your user crontab (crontab -e) might make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Don't edit the crontab file directly. Instead use crontab -e and add the cron entry.

With reference to the [link](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12193)

Comment: In some cases it may be necessary to write to a file directly.  Perhaps if an application were generating a cron job.